Extract metadata from online video
I'm new to working with videos in android development and I'm trying to extract a bitmap and information from a video online. I've tried using ffmpeg, but seems like I'm required to download the video before it can extract the data. I would think taking that approach could burn through a users data.
This is the error I get when I attempt to capture the metadata, but when using a tool like exif I'm able to see attached metadata.
    LaunchedEffect(uri) {
        try {
            val player = ExoPlayer.Builder(context).build().apply {
                setMediaItem(androidx.media3.common.MediaItem.fromUri(uri))
                prepare()
            }

            // Retrieve video duration
            videoLength = player.duration.coerceAtLeast(0L)

            // Retrieve the first frame as a bitmap (ExoPlayer doesn't directly support frame extraction)
            bitmap = getFrameFromVideo(context, uri)

            player.release()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("VideoPlayerView", "Error retrieving video metadata", e)
        }
    }

I get the following error
 E  Error retrieving video frame
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: could not access https://fzxicketxvutmpaagtme.supabase.co/storage/v1/object/public/hotscotsvideos/sample_video.mp4
at android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(MediaMetadataRetriever.java:370)
at VideoPlayerViewKt.getFrameFromVideo(VideoPlayerView.kt:142)
at VideoPlayerViewKt.access$getFrameFromVideo(VideoPlayerView.kt:1)
at VideoPlayerViewKt$VideoPlayerView$1.invokeSuspend(VideoPlayerView.kt:68)
at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:104)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.performTrampolineDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:81)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.access$performTrampolineDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:41)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher$dispatchCallback$1.run(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:57)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)

Any pointers on how I can approach this? My end goal is a bitmap image from a frame and some metadata info.

Is this your backend? If so, generate the details that you need on the backend and serve them separate from the video.

It is, any pointers on where to get started on this?

I assume that site you link to uses exiftool, given its name. If that doesn't work, use ffmpeg. But, you would do this on the server as videos become available (I'm uncertain where/how the videos get there). For example, if you have a video named thisIsFun.mp4, you could have a peer thisIsFun.json file with the relevant metadata bits. You could extend this to having thumbnail files (e.g., thisIsFun.jpeg) if you wanted. They would all be in the same directory (or whatever equivalent structure you have for how the videos are being stored).

Ok that makes sense. I appreciate the help on the design approach.
